can we use keycloak as a login interface for applications without code source ? for iam service
I want to use Keycloak as the Identity and Access Management (IAM) service for my application. My goal is to have the Keycloak login page appear first, and then, if the user is authorized by Keycloak, they can access the rest of the application.
However, I do not have access to the application's source code. I tried configuring a client in Keycloak and added a user to this client, but it didn't work as expected.
Could someone guide me on how to properly set up Keycloak for this scenario? Specifically, I need to know:
Is it possible to integrate Keycloak without the application's source code?
What are the necessary steps to configure Keycloak for this type of integration?
Are there any common pitfalls or additional configurations that I might be missing?

Thank you for your help!

Welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question needs more information. There is no general way to couple an unknown application of unknown architecture to Keycloak SSO. Please add more information about your app, its architecture, its current login mechanism, etc.

Set up a reverse proxy which handles communication with Keycloak. If the user is authorised, the RP then allows access to the unmodified app. Start by looking at Apache mod_auth_openidc, but there are lots of other ways to do it.

@EML , can I use Nginx as a reverse proxy for these situations?

Sure. Most of the web hits are actually for Nginx. I use Apache, and it works well for exactly your situation. This doesn't give you SSO, though. You have to sign in with Keycloak, and then you have to sign in again into your unmodified webapp.

@EML Thank you for your response and advice! I will test with Nginx and will get back with the results.

Hello i have another question,
I would like to know if it's possible to integrate Keycloak into an application without directly including the configuration in the client application's source code. Specifically, I'd like to: Create a form within the client application to allow users to input Keycloak configuration parameters, then transmit this configuration to the backend upon form submission so i can utilize the saved configuration to initialize Keycloak within the client application.
This way, I can utilize Keycloak's IAM service within the client application.
